# Measure the average of elements of a 2d list with the same index in python

Tags: python, numpy, loops

for example I have the following list

```
lst = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'],['7', '8', '9']]
```

I want to find the average of 1+4+7, 2+5+8 and 3+6+9
Any idea on how to create such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
lst = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'],['7', '8', '9']]

from statistics import mean
out = [mean(map(int, x)) for x in zip(*lst)]
```

Output: `[4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 0):

By converting the list to float (or int) typed NumPy array and averaging on the expected axis using `np.average`:

```
np.average(np.asarray(lst, dtype=np.float64), axis=0)

# [4. 5. 6.]
```

*This method is Just by NumPy, and no loops, so **will be faster than loops** on large arrays.*